# How to assert that an array contains an element that matches an expected regexp?

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to assert that an array contains at least one element that matches an expected regular expression, and I am trying to do it in the most by-the-book and the least reinventing-the-wheel way possible.

Ideally I would like to `->assertThat($actualArray, $someConstraintObject)`, where `$someConstraintObject` is a `PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint` instance that does the RightThing™, and is only composed from constraints that ship with PHPUnit, without having to write a new constraint class.

One thing I considered which cannot possibly work: a `LogicalOr` constraint made of `RegularExpression` constraints. Why can't it work? Because `RegularExpression` constraint cannot "bind" an expected value; it can only be *evaluated for* an expected value, and I still have no way of "spreading" the values in an array over that constraint with "or" logic. A `LogicalOr` of `RegularExpression`s would allow me to check one actual value against multiple regular expressions, but it won't allow me to check multiple actual values against one regular expression.

**How do I?**